# Problem with XSLT transformation from ANT to create multiple documents with result-document

Tags: xml, xslt, ant

I want to transform and split a XML document. So i use "result-document" and it works. But when I try to start the XSLT with ANT, i get a output xml document just with the xml declaration.

Source-XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<root>
    <row>
       <name>name1</name>
       <title>bab</title>
    </row>
    <row>
        <name>name2</name>
        <title>bab</title>
    </row>
</root>
```

ANT build example:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project basedir="." name="Split">
        <target name="Transf">     
            <xslt 
                in="${basedir}\source-xml\Output.xml"
                style="${basedir}\xsl\Transf.xsl"
                destdir="${basedir}\xsl\output" 
                processor="org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.TraXLiaison"
                extension=".xml"
                force="yes">
            </xslt>
        </target> 
</project>
```

XSLT section

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

        <xsl:output  
            method="xml" 
            encoding="UTF-8" 
            indent="yes"/>  

        <xsl:template match="/">

            <xsl:for-each select="root/row[name='name1'] | root/row[name='name2']">      
                <xsl:variable name="filename" select="concat('output/',name,'.xml')" />
                <xsl:result-document href="{$filename}" method="xml" encoding="iso-8859-1">     
                    <xsl:for-each select="/">
                        <xsl:element name="topic">  
                            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                        </xsl:element>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:result-document>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

What is wrong? Or is there a alternative to result-document?

Thanks in advance

Comment: In your **ANT build example**, have you mistakenly written `</project>` twice ?

Comment: @Vebbie , you are right! but unfortunately this does not solve my problem

Comment: Do you have Saxon 9 on the class path for your ant project? Is `processor="org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.TraXLiaison"` an attempt to use Saxon 9? `xsl:result-document` is part of XSLT 2/3 and in the Java world supported by Saxon 9, but not by the Apache Xalan XSLT 1 processor, neither the standalone version nor the one integrated in Oracle's JRE.

Comment: http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/using-xsl/xsltfromant.html might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you start by forcing use of Saxon, by adding

```
<factory name="net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl"/>
```